# Why do i still get warnings when using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Tags: java, suppress-warnings

```
class Lenkeliste<T> implements Liste<T>{
  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
  private int iBruk = 0;
  private T[] liste = (T[]) new Object[10];

  public int stoerrelse(){
    return iBruk;
  }
  public void leggTil(int pos, T x) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= iBruk) {
      throw new UgyldigListeIndeks(pos);
    }
    if (iBruk == liste.lenght) {
      @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
      T[] ny = (T[]) new Object[2*iBruk];
      for (int i = pos; i < iBruk; i++) {
        ny[i] = liste[i];
        liste = ny;
        liste[i+1] = liste[i];
      }
      liste[pos] = x;
      iBruk++;
    }
  }
  public void leggTil(T x) {
    if (iBruk == liste.lenght) {
      @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
      T[] ny = (T[]) new Object[2*iBruk];
      for (int i = 0; i < iBruk; i++) {
        ny[i] = liste[i];
        liste = ny;
      }
      liste[iBruk] = x;
      iBruk++;
    }
  }
  public void sett(int pos, T x) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= iBruk) {
      throw new UgyldigListeIndeks(pos);
    }
    liste[pos] = x;
  }
  public T hent(int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= iBruk) {
      throw new UgyldigListeIndeks(pos);
    }
    return liste[pos];
  }
  public T fjern(int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= iBruk) {
      throw new UgyldigListeIndeks(pos);
    }
    T bort = liste[pos];
    for (int i = pos+1; i < iBruk; i++) {
      liste[i-1] = liste[i];
    }
    iBruk--;
    return bort;
  }
  public T fjern() {
    T ut = liste[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < iBruk; i++) {
      liste[i-1] = liste[i];
    }
    iBruk--;
    return ut;
  }
}
```

This is the code i have. The teacher used similar code and got it to work, but I still get warnings.
Here are the errors i get:

```
Lenkeliste.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    if (iBruk == liste.lenght) {
                      ^
  symbol:   variable lenght
  location: variable liste of type T[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Lenkeliste
Lenkeliste.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    if (iBruk == liste.lenght) {
                      ^
  symbol:   variable lenght
  location: variable liste of type T[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Lenkeliste
Note: Lenkeliste.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: `  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})` needs to be before the class declaration.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: These are errors ("compile-time exceptions"), not warnings. Looks like you misspelled `length` as `lenght` - does that fix the problem?

Comment: So there are two issues here. You have some compilation error and warnings. I suggest fixing the compilation errors first.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PiRocks it doesn't need to be, and it's bad practice to put a suppression on a broader scope than necessary, as this may mask an unexpected issue. Far better just to put it on the tree that actually contains the unchecked warning, i.e. the second variable declaration.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree. I was more trying to troubleshoot than provide a "good" answer. This could have been a situation where `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` wasn't working for whatever reason.

Comment: While I'm still here I'm really confused about your choice of variable names @Julie. Is this in norwegian?

Comment: @PiRocks you might also want to question the class name, as this is clearly not a linked list.

Comment: @PiRocks yes , it's norwegian

Comment: Dear @Julie, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your post title, you should write the topic title and then descript what happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
private int iBruk = 0;
private T[] liste = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

The `SuppressWarnings` applies to the declaration of the `int`, not the `T[]`.

Put the suppression on the second declaration.

```
private int iBruk = 0;
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
private T[] liste = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

---

Also, note that the `liste = ny;` lines in the `leggTil` methods shouldn't be inside the loop. If they are, you will only copy the first element of the array to the new array before you overwrite the `liste`, so the subsequent iterations will just set array elements to their current value (i.e. null).

```
  for (int i = 0; i < iBruk; i++) {
    ny[i] = liste[i];
  }
  liste = ny;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following minimal example:

```java
public class Test<T> {
    public Test() {
        Object[] arr = new Object[10];
        T[] new_arr = (T[])arr;
    }
}
```

This yields the following warning:

```
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I can recompile and see details about what unchecked operations I am doing:

```
Test.java:5: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        T[] new_arr = (T[])arr;
                           ^
  required: T[]
  found:    Object[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Test
1 warning
```

I can suppress all unchecked warnings for the whole class:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})// @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") would also work here
public class Test<T> {
    public Test() {
        Object[] arr = new Object[10];
        T[] new_arr = (T[])arr;
    }
}
```

Or I can suppress warnings for a specific method, in this case the constructor:

```java
public class Test<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"}) would also work here
    public Test() {
        Object[] arr = new Object[10];
        T[] new_arr = (T[])arr;
    }
}
```

In your case you also have a variable declaration, so you need to do:

```java
public class Test<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] other_arr = (T[])new Object[10];

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Test() {
        Object[] arr = new Object[10];
        T[] new_arr = (T[])arr;
    }
}
```

It is worth pointing out that your original code has compilation errors, and those should be resolved first.

Lastly these warnings exist for a reason. You should endeavor to write code that doesn't cause them(though how to do that is perhaps a separate stackoverflow question).